Gitlab CI Rules: I expected this to only run if source code files were changed
I have a job in my .gitlab-ci.yaml file with the following rules:
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    changes:
      - src/**/*
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    changes:
      - src/**/*
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
    when: never

I was expecting it to only run in two scenarios:

on any commit made to an open merge request
on any commit to a branch, but only if the MR was not yet open (trying to avoid duplicate runs)

And specifically, only when files inside my source code folder were changed. And this is the part that doesn't seem to be working for me. I just made a commit to a feature branch adding new files to a new folder at the root of the repository. I made no changes to the source code directory. But this job fired on that branch commit. Can anyone decipher why?
It's been a few months, so I don't remember where I got this rules block from, but it was informed by research I did here on SO. And not that I think it affects my current issue (running when no source code was changed), but I am starting to think that the last bullet should be moved to the top. If the rules evaluate in order, I would want to rule out the branch commits while an MR is open, first.

Yes, rules are evaluated in the order written in the spec, from the top. How to avoid surprises is to start with the most specific rules and continue with more generic rules.
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    changes:
      - src/**/*
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
    when: never
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    changes:
      - src/**/*

However, even when using your rules definition it shouldn't start the job unless you had a MR opened and any previous commits in the MR had changes to src/**/*, because in MR pipelines the diff is generated against target branch, not previous commit in source branch.

I think I have discovered how to make things fire on every commit in the MR, even if that specific commit did not change files in the source directory - use the compare_to functionality. Which is kind of the opposite of my original question. But the truth is, I haven't been able to get it to fire "incorrectly" since. Separately, does anyone know if the changes list is OR or AND?

It is OR in changes and there is no way to switch that to AND

good to know, thanks. I wish I had an answer for the original question, but I'm starting to believe there isn't one - it was a fluke or a bug. I'm going to mark this answer as the accepted one, just because it's at least partially helpful.
